# How can I access to the value of a node with groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

It's a really simple question. I have a XML file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test:main xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:test="http://www.testexample.com/test" xmi:id="_BMseoD4mEeiL8o0bAkMKoA">
    <childNode xmi:id="_9_RgZj4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="Boo!" number="1.414"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="_9_RgYz4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="toto" number="42"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="__o_QMT4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="paf" number="12.215"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="_vUeScDy9EeilM5T6mGX42Q" name="pif" number="56.1"/>
</test:main>
```

and I would like to change the value of *number* of *toto*, to give it the value 42.42 for example.
How can I do that ?

Thanks for your attention !

**EDIT :**
The following code works well :

```
import groovy.xml.*

def myTest = '''
<test:main xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:test="http://www.testexample.com/test" xmi:id="_BMseoD4mEeiL8o0bAkMKoA">
    <childNode xmi:id="_9_RgZj4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="Boo!" number="1.414"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="_9_RgYz4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="toto" number="42"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="__o_QMT4lEeiL8o0bAkMKoA" name="paf" number="12.215"/>
    <childNode xmi:id="_vUeScDy9EeilM5T6mGX42Q" name="pif" number="56.1"/>
</test:main>
'''
myTest = new XmlParser(false, true).parseText(myTest)
myTest.childNode.find { obj ->
    obj.@name == 'toto'
}.@number = 42.42

println XmlUtil.serialize( myTest )
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: provide valid xml file..

Comment: Santonja, the code snippet, which is under edit part, seems to be ok and showing the desired output. Isn't it?

Comment: Rao, Yes it's work now !
Thanks for your help @Uchiha_Itachi !

Comment: Glad ! if you feel the answer is useful or acceptable answer, you should accept and up vote the answer. For info refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have used an example xml file. Try with this code :

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil


String xmlfile ='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price name="dollars" mode="online">5.95</price>
<description>
Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
</description>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>'''

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlfile)


root.food.price.find{ it["@name"] =="dollars"}.@ "mode"='offline'


println (XmlUtil.serialize(root))
```

For More operation just read the Groovy doc [link](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)